# How can I set UITableViewCell backgroundColor in section without repeating?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView and i have already set its cell backgroundColor like this.

```
cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ?
            UIColor.Cell.oddBackgroundColor : UIColor.Cell.evenBackgroundColor
```

But when i set up tableView with sections, cells in section set their background color as above again.

For example :

- Cell background colors **without section**:

  - Black
  - Gray
  - Black
  - ...
- Cell background colors **with section**:

  - Section 0

    - Black
    - Gray
    - Black
  - Section 1

    - Black
    - Gray
    - Black

As you can see the last cell in section 0 and the first cell in section 1 are same background color. It must be different and section 1 must different order for its cell background colors.

For example:

Cell background colors **with section**:

- Section 0

  - Black
  - Gray
  - Black
- Section 1

  - Gray
  - Black
  - Gray

How can i do like above example?

Comment: Your calculation needs to include the section, not just the row. And it will need to take into account the number of rows in the previous sections.

Comment: You are using the same logic for all sections. If you want to set the color depending on the previous section you have to count the items

Comment: You are right @rmaddy and vadian. When I store the count of previous section items, how can i implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//var row = indexPath.row
//for i in 0..<indexPath.section {
//    row += tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)
//}
let row = (0..<indexPath.section).reduce(indexPath.row) { $0 + tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: $1) }
cell.backgroundColor = row % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.gray : UIColor.white
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly shorter: `(0..<indexPath.section).reduce(indexPath.row) { $0 + tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: $1) }`